# I cannot get the QUERY function to work with IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I am using the function below to QUERY an IMPORTRANGE range based on `IS NOT NULL` conditions:

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O5DeZ9LFLpGbp8b2aGst57XLEP7ZiOnc-2b552sQLz0","Referrals!A1:AB1080"),"SELECT Col2, Col3, Col4, Col6, Col8, Col22, COL28 WHERE COL28 is not null")
```

I get:

> `#VALUE!` Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN" COL28

I cannot find where I went wrong with the code.

`COL28` is Col AB in the IMPORTRANGE sheet.

Could someone please assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short Answer

Replace `COL28` by `Col28`

## Explanation

Column names are case sensitive.